# Install Yosemite ISO on VMWare Workstation 11

Tags: macos, windows, vmware, virtualization

I have a win 7 computer with vmware workstation 11 and I need to install Yosemite in it. I got the Yosemite OS iso after downloading the os in a mac from the appstore, as outlined in this guide ([Official way to obtain an OS X ISO file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128319/official-way-to-obtain-an-os-x-iso-file)). Now what I cant seem to find anywhere is how to create a vm with that iso. When I create a new vm in workstation it asks for the iso file, then I don't see the option to specify OSX as my OS in the wizard. Is there a way to create a vmx with this iso? Have any of you done this before?

Thanks

Comment: Suggest you read **2. Permitted License Uses and Restrictions.** of the [Apple SLA for OS X Yosemite](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX1010.pdf) as what you're asking violates it and is not a permissible question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac OS X EULA/SLA doesn't allow to run Mac OS X on non-Apple hardware.

VMware Workstation - usually running on non-Apple hardware - adheres to this restriction and doesn't <s>allow</s> offer the possibility to install Mac OS X (even if run in Bootcamp!).

Check [sysprobs](http://www.sysprobs.com/vmware-workstation-8-0-8-0-1-unlocker-to-run-mac-os-x-guest-in-windows-7) to get an impression how the OS X installation in VMware Workstation running in a Bootcamp environment on Apple hardware may work.